# Why splitting the validation set from the dataset using random_split training the model works but ImageFolder loading doesn't

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, resnet

I just can't understand, **why the first one works and the other doesn't**

the transform like this. **This is same for both ways**

```py
  data_transform = {
        "train": transforms.Compose([        
                                    transforms.Resize(224),
                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    # transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
                                    ]),
        
        "val": transforms.Compose([
                                transforms.Resize(224),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                # transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
                                ])
        }
```

and then i use ImageFolder to load train_dataset and val_dataset. **And this is not work.**

```py
    train_data_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(args.data_path,'train'),
                                                      transform=data_transform["train"])
    
    val_data_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(args.data_path,'val'),
                                                    transform=data_transform["val"])
```

**Here is another way**  to get the val_dataset. **And this is work.**

```py
    train_data_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=args.data_path,
                                                      transform=data_transform["train"])

    train_data_set, val_data_set = random_split(train_data_set, [int(len(train_data_set)*0.9),
                                                                len(train_data_set)-int(len(train_data_set)*0.9)],
                                               generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(42))
```

create model code like this.

```py
   model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
   model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(2048, 4)
```

learn_rate is 1e-3 and epoch is 30.All hyper_parameters are the same for both ways
For the way that doesn't work，here in the last 10 epoch output, loss and accuracy.
For the way that  work, the accuracy will reach 90% within 10epoch.

```
[epoch 21] mean loss 1.366: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.66it/s]
[epoch 21] accuracy: 0.261
[epoch 22] mean loss 1.368: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.94it/s]
[epoch 22] accuracy: 0.259
[epoch 23] mean loss 1.366: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  4.00it/s]
[epoch 23] accuracy: 0.259
[epoch 24] mean loss 1.369: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.98it/s]
[epoch 24] accuracy: 0.261
[epoch 25] mean loss 1.366: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.98it/s]
[epoch 25] accuracy: 0.261
[epoch 26] mean loss 1.366: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  4.01it/s]
[epoch 26] accuracy: 0.261
[epoch 27] mean loss 1.366: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.98it/s]
[epoch 27] accuracy: 0.261
[epoch 28] mean loss 1.365: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.89it/s]
[epoch 28] accuracy: 0.261
[epoch 29] mean loss 1.365: 100%|█| 59/59 [
100%|██████| 10/10 [00:02<00:00,  3.92it/s]
[epoch 29] accuracy: 0.261
```

The dataset has about a few thousand images, divided into four categories

all code in here

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision

import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from models.resnet import resnet50
from models.mobilenet import mobilenet_v3_large
import math
from  torch.utils.data import Subset,random_split
import argparse
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.optim.lr_scheduler as lr_scheduler

from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
import sys

from apex import amp


def train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch):
    model.train()
    loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
    mean_loss = torch.zeros(1).to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    data_loader = tqdm(data_loader, file=sys.stdout)

    for step, data in enumerate(data_loader):
        images, labels = data
        images,labels = images.to(device),labels.to(device)
        pred = model(images)

        loss = loss_function(pred, labels)
        
        with amp.scale_loss(loss, optimizer) as scaled_loss:
            scaled_loss.backward()
        # loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        mean_loss = (mean_loss * step + loss.detach()) / (step + 1)  # update mean losses

        
        data_loader.desc = "[epoch {}] mean loss {}".format(epoch, round(mean_loss.item(), 3))

        if not torch.isfinite(loss):
            print('WARNING: non-finite loss, ending training ', loss)
            sys.exit(1)
    return mean_loss.item()


@torch.no_grad()
def evaluate(model, data_loader, device):
    model.eval()

   
    sum_num = torch.zeros(1).to(device)

    
    data_loader = tqdm(data_loader, file=sys.stdout)

    for step, data in enumerate(data_loader):
        images, labels = data
        images,labels = images.to(device),labels.to(device)
        pred = model(images)
        pred = torch.max(pred, dim=1)[1]
        sum_num += torch.eq(pred, labels).sum()

    return sum_num.item()

def main(args):
    if torch.cuda.is_available() is False:
        raise EnvironmentError("not find GPU device for training.")

    device = torch.device(args.device)
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    weights_path = args.weights

    tb_writer = SummaryWriter('log')
    if os.path.exists("./weights") is False:
        os.makedirs("./weights")


    data_transform = {
        "train": transforms.Compose([        
                                    # transforms.Resize(224),
                                    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    # transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
                                    ]),
        
        "val": transforms.Compose([
                                transforms.Resize(224),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                # transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
                                ])
        }

    train_data_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(args.data_path,'train'),
                                                      transform=data_transform["train"])
    # val_data_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=os.path.join(args.data_path,'val'),
    #                                                 transform=data_transform["val"])
    
    
    # train_data_set = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=args.data_path,
    #                                                   transform=data_transform["train"])
    print('训练图片总数量：',len(train_data_set))
    print(train_data_set.class_to_idx)
    
    train_data_set, val_data_set = random_split(train_data_set,[int(len(train_data_set)*0.9),
                                                                len(train_data_set)-int(len(train_data_set)*0.9)],
                                               generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(0))
    
    # number of workers
    nw = 4
    print('Using {} dataloader workers'.format(nw))
    
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_data_set,
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                pin_memory=True,
                                num_workers=nw)

    val_loader = DataLoader(val_data_set,
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                pin_memory=True,
                                num_workers=nw)

    
    model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=args.pretrain)
    model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(2048, args.num_classes)
    
    
    
    if os.path.exists(weights_path):
        weights_dict = torch.load(weights_path)
        load_weights_dict = {k: v for k, v in weights_dict.items()
                             if model.state_dict()[k].numel() == v.numel()}
        model.load_state_dict(load_weights_dict, strict=False)
        print("load weights from {}".format(weights_path))
    
    # 转移到gpu上
    model = model.to(device)

    # 是否冻结权重
    if args.freeze_layers:
        for name, para in model.named_parameters():
            # 除最后的全连接层外，其他权重全部冻结
            if "fc" not in name:
                para.requires_grad_(False)
    
    # optimizer
    pg = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
    # optimizer = optim.SGD(pg, lr=args.lr, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.005)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(pg, lr=args.lr, weight_decay=0.005, amsgrad=True)
    model, optimizer = amp.initialize(model, optimizer, opt_level="O1")
    
    # Scheduler https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01187.pdf
    # lf = lambda x: ((1 + math.cos(x * math.pi / args.epochs)) / 2) * (1 - args.lrf) + args.lrf  # cosine
    # scheduler = lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=lf)
    scheduler = lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[5, 15, 40, 80], gamma=0.1)
    
    best_acc = 0.0
    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        mean_loss = train_one_epoch(model=model,
                                    optimizer=optimizer,
                                    data_loader=train_loader,
                                    device=device,
                                    epoch=epoch)

        scheduler.step()

        sum_num = evaluate(model=model,
                           data_loader=val_loader,
                           device=device)
        
        acc = sum_num / len(val_data_set)
        
        tqdm.write("[epoch {}] accuracy: {}".format(epoch, round(acc, 3)))
        tags = ["loss", "accuracy", "learning_rate"]
        tb_writer.add_scalar(tags[0], mean_loss, epoch)
        tb_writer.add_scalar(tags[1], acc, epoch)
        tb_writer.add_scalar(tags[2], optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"], epoch)
            
        # 保存acc 最高模型
        if acc>=best_acc:
            best_acc = acc
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join("weights","model-best.pth"))
        
        # 保存最终模型
        if epoch == args.epochs - 1:
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join("weights","model-final.pth"))
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--num-classes', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=48)
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=1e-4)
    parser.add_argument('--lrf', type=float, default=1e-1)
    
    # 数据集所在根目录
    parser.add_argument('--data-path', type=str, default="/media/msi/d/lege_pose_crowed")

    # 是否加载预训练权重
    parser.add_argument('--weights', type=str, default="",
                        help='initial weights path')
    
    parser.add_argument('--freeze-layers',action="store_true",help="default is False,when get this value ,freeze all layers")
    
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='cuda', help='device id (i.e. 0 or 0,1 or cpu)')
    
    
    parser.add_argument('--pretrain', action="store_true", help='default is False,when set,load pretrain model')
    
    opt = parser.parse_args()

    main(opt)
```

Comment: Can you show your inference and evaluation code?

Comment: yeah.
```python
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because I did not set `shuffle=True`. When I set this, the result is the same.